# Groovy XmlSlurper and inserting child nodes

Tags: xml, groovy

Is it possible to use the [Groovy's XMLSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper) and insert child nodes at an index?

Currently the GPathResult class has putAt(index) and appendNode(). The first replaces the element at the index rather than inserting and the second adds to the end.

I am tied to XmlSlurper rather than XmlParser unfortunately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Found it. So simple (*crazy awesome* Groovy). All it takes is to add the node after the node in question using a closure and the **+** operator.

*For example:*

```
//Add the ac:MessageStatus after ac:MessageDateTime (this is an Acord message hence the ac:)
root.'ac:MessageDateTime' + {
    'ac:MessageStatus' { 
        'ac:MessageStatusCode'('ac:Success') 
        'ac:SuccessCode'('ac:Success') 
    }
}
```

Comment: Voted up, but I think a basic example without namespaces would be a bit more readable.

Comment: Feel free to edit. Namespaces are part of my environment and part of the problem I was addressing.

Comment: perfection, that's exactly what I needed. The documentation is not clear about the use of plus()